# Cat/Bunny/Kangaroo Girl Fighting a Monster in forest Cartoon Clip saw On Facebook

Tags: story-identification, cartoon

I saw this cartoon one or two years ago in video on Facebook and thought I had saved it but apparently not.

It was a video of a little half human half animal (pointy ears like a bunny, cat or kangaroo) girl (a kid, maybe 6-13 yrs?) that was sleeping in a forest and woke up to fight a monster. I think she had a pet of some sort too. I remember the clip ended with her finding her friends and they were all teasing each other sitting under a tree looking out over a field... or maybe a city or something. The group of half-humans were representative of people of color. The show was in English.

It looked really similar to Threadworlds. I know it is not because Threadworlds is an unreleased comic book and wouldn't have any video animation to it yet. But the character creation looked reaaaaally similar to this: [image]

Would love to find this show (if it's a show) as it's rarer to find a diverse cast in well-done fantasy/adventure cartoons. It didn't really look like an anime but might be seen as that. The style was more cartoon I'd say. But who knows some people think Adventure Time is anime so...

I saw it I wanna say a year or two ago and keep going back to look for it. It's not She-Ra.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  You should check out the [suggestions](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/101407) for asking a good story-id question.  There might be some points there that trigger additional memories.

Comment: Any change it to be Squirrel Girl?

Comment: Not Squirrel Girl, but that looks interesting!

Comment: Maybe Wakfu? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wakfu_(TV_series)

Comment: How long was the cartoon? Angry Alien has the 30 second bunny theater...movies are condensed to 30 seconds and star bunnies.

Comment: Not Wakfu or Angry Alien. It was a five minute or so clip I saw on facebook onetime. It had a more of adventure time spliced with Studio Ghibli kind of feel.

Comment: Added the threadworlds picture above. Does that look similar to any cartoons/animation/video you all have seen?